# Assigining objects from a list with a For-Loop in r

Tags: r, function, for-loop, assign

I'm attempting to use a for loop to run a function on several data frames that will change, rename, and then delete the originals. Everything works within the function but I am having some trouble coming up with the syntax on how to run the for loop. I have written a simple example that recreates my issue:

```
Sample_1<-c(1,2,3,4)
Sample_2<-c(2,4,6,8)
Sample_3<-c(11,13,15)
Samples<-c(1,2,3)
for (i in Samples){
  assign(paste0("Mean_",i),mean(paste0("Sample_",i)))
}
```

Thanks up front for any help with this.

Comment: Do not use `assign`. Put your samples in a list and iterate over the list. You can then put the mean values in a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the mean statement - it's trying to find the mean of the string, not the actual variable.  Try adding a `get` statement.

```
for (i in Samples){
  assign(paste0("Mean_",i),mean(get(paste0("Sample_",i))))
}
```